# Neo4j 3.5 Query Performance Issue

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

I have following query running in neo4j (community 3.5)

```sql
MATCH (a:master_node:PERF:Application)-[r1]->(n:master_node:PERF)-[r:AFFINITY]->(m:master_node:PERF)<-[r2]-(a1:master_node:PERF:Application)
WHERE exists(n.latest_ingestion)
  AND exists(m.latest_ingestion)
  AND id(a) <> id(a1)
MERGE (a)<-[:APP_AFFINITY]-(a1)
```

and my configurations for neo4j are as follows:

```
heap_size : 8GB
page_cache : 4GB
```

and I have Indexes for the label(Application) on property(name) and above query running over 100k nodes.But the Query is running for longer time and consuming so much of memory.

Please help me out to improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `name` property in this query, so your index won't help. The only indexes that may help would be on `:master_node(latest_ingestion)` or `:PERF(latest_ingestion)`, that may change the query from using label scans to index scans, depending on db statistics.

Also, you may want to consider batching these updates, likely using `apoc.periodic.iterate()` from APOC procedures. Something like:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
  MATCH (a:master_node:PERF:Application)-->(n:master_node:PERF)-[:AFFINITY]->(m:master_node:PERF)<--(a1:master_node:PERF:Application)
  WHERE exists(n.latest_ingestion)
    AND exists(m.latest_ingestion)
    AND id(a) <> id(a1)
  RETURN a, a1",
  "MERGE (a)<-[:APP_AFFINITY]-(a1)", 
  {}) YIELD batches, total, errorMessages
RETURN batches, total, errorMessages
```

Comment: Thank u so much for responding...will test it using both indexes and APOC and let u know..Thanks once again for responding